# My javascript function (url) doesnt go to the php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, include

I have a question which is probably easy to solve but due to my lack of javascripting skills I find it rather hard.

I am using a function to auto-complete database info in a search bar. For that I'm using this javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".search").keyup(function(){ 
            var inputSearch = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'searchword='+ inputSearch;

            if(inputSearch!=''){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://marceldepender.nl:2222/CMD_FILE_MANAGER/domains/marceldepender.nl/public_html/Recap/wp-content/themes/radiate/templates/search.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#divResult").html(html).show();
                    }
                });     
            }

            return false;    
       });

     jQuery("#divResult").live("click",function(e){ 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#inputSearch').val(decoded);
     });

    jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
            jQuery("#divResult").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
    $('#inputSearch').click(function(){
        jQuery("#divResult").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see in the first part of the function, there is a value called url: this url includes (at least I think that is what it does) a certain php page when the if statement is true. This php page (search.php) does a query and gives output related to the search terms.

Though for some reason, the javascript function doesn't go to that search.php page. I have done / tested several things:

1. IN the original document the url was just plan: url: "search.php", - I changed it to the entire link where the search.php is on though since the previous url didn't work (the new one doesn't either though).
2. I changed the search.php to some easy echo code just so I know the page is being included / redirected to.

For some reason (and I think it is because the search.php isn't being included) the code doesn't work.. The page where the javascript function is on, is located on a directadmin files on the net, the search.php is also located in this same map.

So the question is: why isn't my search.php included and how can I fix this?

For some better understanding of my search.php code I inserted the original code below:

```
<?php
    include('includes/db.php');

    if($_POST){
        $q=$_POST['searchword'];
        $sql_res=mysql_query("select uid,username,email,media,country from test_auto_complete where username like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' order by uid LIMIT 5");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)){
            $username=$row['username'];
            $email=$row['email'];
            $media=$row['media'];
            $country=$row['country'];
            $b_username='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
            $b_email='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
            $final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
            $final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);
?>
<div class="display_box" align="left">
<img src="<?php echo $media; ?>" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" /><span class="name"><?php echo $final_username; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/><?php echo $final_email; ?><br/>
<span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999"><?php echo $country; ?></span></div>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried entering your URL in my browser but it prompts me with a direct admin login. Does your .htacces block users from accesing this file?

Comment: Do you have firebug? In firebug you can see what ajax calls are being made + responses..

Comment: @Stijn Bernards I think it does, and that also gave me an idea to put the file in an upload documents page (which i thought others could access). So i changed the url but this still doesnt work..

Comment: @Naruto no i haven't, neither i know what it is so will look into it;)

Comment: @Stijn Bernards Ok, so indeed i think it doesn't go to the page is because it is on Directadmin and it needs a login or something, i didn't see this obviously because i was always logged in. So the question is, how can i avoid this or go around it?

Comment: By keeping your "manual" Admin Tool and your REST API two different scripts

Comment: @MaxBumaye Dont quite know what you mean by this, could you elaborate it a bit? I was thinking to perhaps just paste the search.php code in the same page document as the javascript function? Don't quite know then however how to make it interact? Would that for example mean i dont longer need the url:

Comment: well... as I have read in the answers it appears to me that you are trying to send a request to somephppage.php. This is also the php file you are accessing through the browser to monitor(??  "it is on Directadmin") and is located in some kind of secured htaccess area for some reason. You should create a different.php file on the server to handle programmatical requests. Read about REST API - just google it :P